# Al enviar datos de mi formulario con AJAX se guarda dos veces el mismo registro

Tags: html, ajax, nodejs

Tengo un problema al enviar datos de mi formulario en ajax de la siguiente forma, en la base de datos se guarda dos veces el mismo registro lo cual no deberia de ser lo correcto, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
$('#recordsForm').on('submit', function(){
    let cod_history = $('#cod_history');
    let name_person = $('#name_person');
    let specialty = $('#specialty');
    let turn = $('#turn');
    let office = $('#office');

    $.ajax({
      url: '/records/add',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        cod_history: cod_history.val(),
        name_person: name_person.val(),
        specialty: specialty.val(),
        turn: turn.val(),
        office: office.val()
      },
      success: function (res){
        console.log(res);
      }
    })});
```

No se en que parte estoy haciendo mal ya que mi form seria de la siguiente forma:

```html
<form id="recordsForm" action="/records/add" method="POST">
        <div class="form row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="cod_history">Código: </label>
            <input type="text" id="cod_history" name="cod_history" class="form-control" placeholder="Codigo" autofocus required>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="name_person">Nombre encargado: </label>
            <input type="text" id="name_person" name="name_person" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del encargado" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="specialty">Especialidad: </label>
            <input type="text" id="specialty" name="specialty" class="form-control" placeholder="Especialidad" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="turn">Turno: </label>
            <select id="turn" name="turn" class="form-control" required>
         <option selected>Seleccionar</option>
        <option value="Mañana">Mañana</option>
        <option value="Tarde">Tarde</option>
       </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label for="office">Consultorio</label>
            <input type="text" id="office" name="office" class="form-control" placeholder="Consultorio" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Registrar salida</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

y en nodejs estoy recibiendo los datos de la siguiente forma:

```js
router.post('/records/add',async(req,res)=>{
 const { cod_history, name_person, specialty, office, turn} = req.body;
 const records = new Records({cod_history, name_person, specialty, office, turn});
 await records.save();
 res.redirect('/records');
 const msg = {status: 'Registro guardado'};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te sucede es que al apretar el botón del formulario éste se envía hacia el action indicado, además tienes una función asociada al evento de envío del formulario (que hace la misma petición que el formulario en si) . Para resolver quita el tipo submit del botón por:

```
Type="button"
```

Así el botón no enviará el formulario al hacer click, además tendrás que cambiar la asociación del evento ya que ahora tendrías que asociar el evento click del botón.

En resumen, cuando colocas un botón en un formulario éste por defecto es de tipo submit (en tu caso hasta lo específicas) por ende al pulsarlo se enviará el formulario al action indicado.

Si lo que quieres es usar plenamente ajax no tienes ni que indicar el action ni el tipo de método en el formulario si quiera ya que la petición la armas desde el javascript como lo estas haciendo.